# Restart Kernel Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just started using Python 3 on Jupyter so I'm not really confortable with it.  When I open a file with some commands, if I try to run it, the screen will give me back errors saying that the variables are not defined.

If I try to run directly `filename.find("2019")` it gives an error back. So when I open a file should, as first step, run all the cells?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " When I open a file in file with some commands". Provide us with some screenshots or a better description?

Comment: I made an edit, thanks for the help.

Comment: You cannot run `filename.find("2019")` directly. You first have to define `filename`, before using `filename`. I would suggest doing a tutorial on jupyter, e.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ952vChhuI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally speaking, when you open an existing notebook and want to add some code to it at the end, you should first run all the existing cells. You can do this from the menu: Cell -> Run All. Otherwise you would have no proper way of testing your additional code, since it may depend on changes to the namespace in the preceding code.

If the notebook wasn't active so far in that Jupyter session, there is no need to restart the kernel. Jupyter starts a separate kernel instance for every notebook you open.